# Join slices to full image with image_slicer.py

Tags: python, image, join, python-imaging-library

I'm working with `image_slicer` from `PyPi`.
I have cut an Image into sub images of equal size. The sub images are not held in ram but stored to the HD.

Now I need to set the sub images back into a full images. My problem is that I don't understand how it is processed.

> ## code of join implementaion
>
> ```
>  def join(tiles):
>   """
>   @param ``tiles`` - Tuple of ``Image`` instances.
>   @return ``Image`` instance.
>   """
>     im = Image.new('RGB', get_combined_size(tiles), None)
>     columns, rows = calc_columns_rows(len(tiles))
>   for tile in tiles:         
>     Im.paste(tile.image, tile.coords)
>     return im
> ```

So the join function need objects of type "tiles" but if we have a look the the original [code](https://github.com/samdobson/image_slicer/blob/master/image_slicer/main.py) we see that the function `slice`, which produces and saves the tiles only saves png-files, which does not contain any meta information, such as coordination or position, which are needed for joining.

So my question is, how can I join the slices that are produced by the `slice` function properly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**slice** returns a tuple of tiles you can then use with **join**

If you already have tiles stored in a directory, load them with

```
tiles = image_slicer.open_images_in(img_dir)
```

That function figures out the coordinates based on the filenames which isn't ideal but works.

Comment: the slices are already saved, so I don't have any tile information

Comment: As long as they have the coordinates in the name (like "_01_05.jpg") using `open_images_in(directory)` should work